# Create a raster with ranges from another raster

Tags: raster, r, date

I have a raster that contains values ranging from 1-180. I am looking for a way to create a new raster where if the values of a cell in the original raster is between 1-10 the new raster cell gets the value of 1, 11-20 gets the value of 2 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ceiling`.

Here is an example in which a raster with values in the interval [1,180] is generated randomly and reclassified.  The code then produces a scatterplot of the original and reclassified values to show it has worked correctly. To make it clear that the endpoints of each class are being treated properly (because this is where bugs can arise), the values of the raster are chosen to be even numbers 2, 4, 6, ..., 178, 180.  However, this method will work with floating-point values just as well.  By looking closely at the plot, whose vertical grid lines are at multiples of 10, you can see that the numbers 10, 20, ..., 180 are reclassified as intended (into groups 1, 2, ..., 18) and not (mistakenly) into the next higher group.

(*Viewing a scatterplot of the results of a reclassification is always a good idea:* it quickly reveals any mistakes which otherwise might be difficult to see in maps of the two rasters.)

```
# Generate a raster.
library(raster)
r <- raster(matrix(sample(seq(2, 180, by=2), 4000, replace=TRUE), 50, 80))

# Reclassify it.
r.0 <- ceiling(r/10)

# Check the results with a plot.
plot(r, r.0, xlab="Original Value", ylab="Category", cex=0.9, pch=16, col="Orange")
abline(v=seq(0, 180, by=10), col="#00000010")
abline(h=seq(0, 20, by=5), col="#00000010")
```

[image: ![Plot]

"Quick and simple" indeed is the right way to formulate this question: in general, direct arithmetic operations (like `ceiling`) will be faster and more reliable than a generic reclassification (based on looking up values in user-defined intervals).

Comment: Great use of `ceiling`. I completely overlooked that OPs question was aimed at regular intervals, for which `reclassify` is inferior.

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple with the `reclassify` function from the `raster`package which takes a 3 column matrix with the values `(from, to, becomes)` or a vector that can be converted to such with `byrow=True`.

In your case:

```
rcl_vec <- c(0,10,1,
             11,20,2,
             ...)
rcl_mat <- matrix(rcl_vec, ncol=3, byrow=True)
reclassified_raster <- reclassify(raster_img, rcl_mat)
# or shorter
reclassified_raster <- reclassify(raster_img, rcl_vec)
```

Edit:

This method is best employed when you want user-defined value ranges instead of evenly spaced ones.